# LetsEncrypt WordPress on the Raspberry Pi - Nice url's give 404 with https, http works

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error

I setup WordPress on my Raspberry Pi and used LetsEncrypt to secure it. The HTTPS links will work with Post ID permalinks. They return a 404 when I change the permalinks to anything else.

Here is my .htaccess file. If you need anything else just let me know. I'm really stumped here.

```
10 # BEGIN WordPress
 11 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 12 RewriteEngine On
 13 RewriteBase /
 14 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 15 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 16 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 17 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 18 </IfModule>
 19 
 20 # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the conflict.

In the default-ssl file I changed the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com/>    # added full directory path                                                            
  Options FollowSymLinks                                                      
  AllowOverride All                  # change None to ALL                                              
</Directory>
```

Comment: For the AllowOverride, the minimum you need is AllowOverride FileInfo, in order for rewrite rules to work in .htaccess files. But AllowOverride All works too.